# Show that $8x^4 −16x^3 +16x^2 −8x+k = 0$ has at least one non-real root for all real $k$. Find the sum of the non-real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> Show that $8x^4 −16x^3 +16x^2 −8x+k = 0$ has at least one non-real root for all real $k$. Find the sum of the non-real roots.

Since this polynomial looks so symmetric, I think factoring it might help. We have that $8(x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x) = 8x(x-1)(x^2-x+1)= -k$. Then I'm not sure how to work with the non-real root part, but I think that $(x^2-x+1)$ may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use derivatives, if you want to continue from your partial attempt.

$(x^2-x)(x^2-x+1) = (x^2-x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4} = ((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{1}{4}$.

We can obviously see that it's decreasing for $x < \frac{1}{2}$ and increasing for $x > \frac{1}{2}$.

We certainly know more, since we want to find all $x$ such that:

$((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4})^2 = c$

where $c$ is some real.

$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = \pm\sqrt{c}-\frac{1}{4}$.

$x = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\pm\sqrt{c}-\frac{1}{4}}$. [The signs are independent.]

All roots come in pairs with the outer "$\pm$". So the answer just depends on how many non-real roots. If you want to determine exactly when it has $2$ or $4$ non-real roots, just split into cases based on the $\sqrt{}$, giving the cases $c < 0$, or $0 \le c < \frac{1}{16}$, or $\frac{1}{16} \le c$. You may need to handle the boundaries separately if you don't want to count double roots as separate.

Comment: How does this prove it?

Comment: @user19405892: If you ignore the constant and scale factor, it goes down then up.. so how many times can a horizontal line cut it?

Comment: @user19405892: You can even solve for the real roots this way!

Comment: @user21820 That's exactly what first derivative does. It proves that 0.5 is the local minima.

Comment: @WinVineeth: The first derivative doesn't let you get a closed form for the roots.

Comment: What about the sum?

Comment: @user19405892: Solve for the roots then find the sum.

Comment: What does "We can obviously see that it's decreasing for $x < \frac{1}{2}$ and increasing for $x > \frac{1}{2}$" tell us?

Comment: @user19405892: Erm, why don't you try answering my question? How many times can a horizontal line cut the (strictly) decreasing part of the graph of the expression for $x < \frac{1}{2}$? Anyway even if you don't get that, you can just directly find all possible roots (closed form) using what I've shown you. That should be easy for you.

Comment: I don't see how the function is decreasing, anywhere.

Comment: @user19405892: What? When $x < \frac{1}{2}$ it clearly decreases as $x$ increases. If you can't see why, plug in some numbers to get a feel for what is happening. And do you see that given what I said you can just solve for the roots directly without even looking at the graph?

Comment: Yes, I see that. But $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 \geq 0$, so I don't see how it can decrease.

Comment: @user19405892: You clearly don't know the meaning of "decreasing". (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decreasing_function for picture.) In any case I spelt it out already in my last comment; "When $x < \frac{1}{2}$ [the value of the expression] decreases as $x$ increases." Don't ignore the phrase "as $x$ increases".

Comment: @user19405892: By the way, in case it wasn't obvious, whenever you see a graph symmetrical about a vertical line you should expect a symmetrical formula about the line of symmetry and it is usually good to find it. After factorizing you would then have looked for how to combine factors to get it into a symmetrical form, which would give you the form I showed.

Comment: @user21820 Ah, I see what you mean. So the function can have $2$ or $0$ real roots and that proves it?

Comment: @user19405892: Yes. To get the sum the easiest way is still via the closed form solution, or equivalently noting that the expression is symmetric about $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So the solutions sum to $0$?

Comment: @user19405892: Erm? The solutions are symmetric about the line of symmetry..

Comment: @user21820 I still find it hard because we have to find the sum of the non real roots, which there could be $2$ or $4$ of. How do I take this into account and how do I find, which are non real?

Comment: @user19405892: I've updated my answer to sketch that part.

Comment: The sum of the roots is $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @user19405892: Right. Do you completely understand the solution now?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** To show that there is at least one nonreal root, we can observe the second derivative of the polynomial $p(x)$ on the l.h.s. is
$$p''(x) = 32(3 x^2 - 3 x + 1);$$
this has discriminant $32^2 \cdot (-3) < 0$ and hence has the same sign for all $x$. What does this tell you about the number of real roots $p(x)$ can have?

For the sum, it's easier to work in the variable $x = u - \tfrac{1}{2}$. Then, $$p(x) = q(u) := 8 u^4 + 4 u^2 + \left(k - \tfrac{3}{2}\right) ,$$ which in particular is even. So, if $r$ is a root of $q(u)$, then so is $-r$, and hence $-\frac{1}{2} \pm r$ are roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: It must have two real roots or $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct---can you see why? (To be clear, $p$ can have one root of multiplicity $2$ for a critical value of $k$.)

Comment: What about the sum?

Comment: Also I don't get your determinant.

Comment: I've added a hint for dealing with the sum. As for the determinant, do you not understand what the determinant is, how it was computed, or how it leads to the conclusion that $p''(x)$ has the same sign for all $x$?

Comment: How it leads to the conclusion that $p''(x)$ has the same sign.

Comment: The polynomial $p''$ is a quadratic. Since its discriminant is negative, it has no real roots, and so either $p''$ is positive everywhere or negative everywhere.

Comment: You say discriminant and determinant, which do you mean?

Comment: Oops, yes, I mean discriminant---of course, there's no sense of determinant that makes sense here.

Comment: Sorry it's just very confusing what you are saying. Why are you talking about the discriminant being negative? Why not just the function?

Comment: Computing the discriminant of a quadratic is an efficient way to tell how many roots it has, and in particular determine whether it changes sign anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The I-take-no-clever-shortcuts approach:

I consider the polynomial $p(x)=8x^4-16x^3+16x^2-8x$.

I try to rewrite $p(x)$ as something of the form  $d(ax^2+bx+c)^2$ because if it is so, I know how to find the roots. The $d$ coefficient is there only because I like my leading coefficient of $x^4$ to be rational, and $8$ is not a square, but $8/2=4=2^2$ it is. So let me assume $d=2$, which is like to say I'm considering the coefficients of $p(x)/2$

Expanding $(ax^2+bx+c)^2$ I find 
$$a^2x^4 + 2 a b x^3 +(b^2 + 2 a c) x^2+2 b c x+c^2$$

it is not difficult to see if there is a choice (actually there are two with opposite signs) of $a,b,c$ that makes the above polynomial equal to the source one, minus the constant terms (that we will send to the right anyway).

Indeed we can immediately find that $a=\pm 2$. Let me try with $a=2$. From that I derive (from the coefficient of $x^3$) that $b=-2$ and then $c=1$.

All in all we have obtained $p(x)=2(2x^2-2x+1)^2 -2$ and thus 
that $p(x)=-k$ can be rewritten as 
$$
2(2x^2-2x+1)^2 = 2-k
$$

Now, it is not difficult to work out an expression for the roots of this equation. You simply consider the two equations (one for each sign)
$$
2x^2-2x+1 = \pm \sqrt{1-k/2}
$$
and solve for $x$ using the classic formula. At the end you obtain four solutions, namely
$$
x_{1,2,3,4}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{-1\pm\sqrt{4-2k}}\right)
$$

From here, it is easy to answer the questions of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative of the root has $1$ real root and $2$ imaginary roots which are $0.5, 0.5+0.5i, 0.5-0.5i$. Hence, you can say that The equation can have only 2 real roots at the maximum. Since it is a fourth order equation, there must be at least $2$ imaginary roots.

Comment: How does the roots of the derivative tell you about the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: @user19405892 , Roots of the derivative are the positions of local maxima or minima. Having only one real root means that there is only one local maxima or minima. This means The plot changes direction only once. So, you can have only two roots(It can cross x-axis only twice at the maximum)

Comment: Your method of using the derivative works for general polynomials, but does not give any way to find the actual roots, as desired in this case.